# YouTube iFrame API: no ready call, no error call

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to detect the "flash out of date" error in my code. The player object exists yet no callbacks are called.

```
var player = new YT.Player( 'pp-yt-player-div-id',
    {
        height: '50',
        width: '50',
        playerVars:
        {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            rel: 0
        },
        events:
        {
            onReady: function( event )
            {
                this.onReady();
            }.bind( this ),
            onStateChange: function( event )
            {
                this.onStateChange( event );
            }.bind( this ),
            onError: function( event )
            {
                console.log( 'on error: '+event );
                this.onError( event );
            }.bind( this )
        }
    } );
```

Is there a good way to detect the error in this scenario?

Comment: _"Is there a good way to detect the 'Flash out of date' error in this scenario?"_ No because you're code is not involving any Flash content. If you're HTML code is not embedding an **.swf** file then you're not using Flash... Youtube uses a video tag, JS, CSS an PHP...

Comment: all youtube videos say right on the player "flash out of date." whatever the error actually is, the youtube iframe API is not allowing me to detect it.

Comment: Is the text selectable? if yes, maybe just do a String search for "Flash out of date" in the iframe? Which browser used? Which test link? I live in Chrome browser so I never see such issues..

Comment: the error was happening on an older safari - 6.2.8 i believe. but i recently upgraded and can no longer reproduce the error. it just bugged me that there was no good way to detect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why, but no error is called even though there is definitely an error. The only solution i can determine is a timeout hack which is obviously nasty.

```js
var readyError = false;
var waitTimer = setTimeout( function()
{
    readyError = true;
    throw new Error( 'YouTube player not initializing. Possible Flash out of date error.' );
}, 10000 );

var ytPlayer = new YT.Player( 'youtube-player-id', {
  events: {
    onReady: function(e) {
      clearTimeout(waitTimer); 
    },
    onStateChange: function(e) {
      ... 
    },
    onError: function(e) {
      ... 
    } 
  } } );
```